# Software for drawing flow networks

Tags: graph, graph-drawing, network-flow

I need to draw some flow networks like the following:
[image]

Does anyone know a program that can do that?

Answer (score 3):

GraphViz is the tool you need.

http://www.graphviz.org/

This in the gallery looks close to what you want:
http://www.graphviz.org/content/fsm

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can create graphs like the following with LibreOffice Draw in Ubuntu.

[image]